# Camel file route does not copy file from Absolute Uri

Tags: java, apache-camel

Here is my code

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        from("file:/C/Users/john/Desktop/inbox?noop=true")
        .to("file:/C/Users/john/Desktop/outbox")
        .process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("test " + exchange.toString());
            }
        });
    }
});

context.start();
```

The same works fine if I use `file://data/inbox?noop=true` and `file:data/outbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use colon after name of disk - C:

```
from("file:C:/Users/john/Desktop/inbox?noop=true")
```

read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Comment: Thank you very much for help, you are right but I had also another problem. I have written code in main method in it got terminated before camel execution , I added Thread.sleep(50000) and it works after that.

Comment: btw   "file:///C:/Users/john/Desktop/inbox?noop=true"        and "file:C:/Users/john/Desktop/inbox?noop=true" are right uris

Comment: I use camel spring:
`code`
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;

public class AppMain {
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("file:./conf/spring-context.xml");
        main.enableHangupSupport();
        main.run();
    }
}
`code`

Comment: I too, I did this one just for test ))

Answer (score 0):

You are using the windows, the route should be like this

```
from("file:\\C\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\inbox?noop=true")
                        .to("file:\\C\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\outbox")
```

Comment: I think there should be  :   after C , as mentioned by @Oleg

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time to figure out how to copy files from disk root on windows,

```
public static final String FROM = "file:D:?noop=true";
public static final String TO = "file:D:/camel/";

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

    ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(FROM).to(TO).end();
        }
    });
    ctx.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    ctx.stop();
}
```

Comment: This merely combines the question text with the existin accepted answer (which only shows which bit to change). As such it doesn't really add anything over and above that answer does it?